# Constructing a Random Variable According to a Probability Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and a measure space $(M, \mathcal B )$ can we construct a random variable $X:\Omega \to M$ such that $X$ is distributed according to  some probability measure $P^* $ on $\Omega $? Similar questions have been asked here where we can choose $P^*$ to be $P$ and $M$ to be $\Omega $ where $X=id$ suffices or for $M=\mathbb R$ and we can use inverse transform sampling. I'm trying to understand an instance where neither is the case. It goes as follows:

We start with some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and define a sequence $\xi_n$ of random variables with values in the measure space $M$, the set of non-negative finite measures on $[0,T] \times \mathbb R ^d$ with the weak topology. For each $\xi_n$ we have an induced probability measure $P_n$ on $M$. Via a tightness argument, we can then show, that these $P_n$ (or rather a subsequence) converge weakly to some probability measure $P^∗$
on $M$. Then the paper goes on to say, we simply denote by $\xi$ a random variable on $M$
distributed according to $P^∗$. This is where I'm lost. How can we construct such a random variable? Does it necessarily exist?

We can choose the space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ freely, so we can choose $\Omega = M$. But the issue is, $P^* $ depends on the choice of $P$, so we can't just choose $P=P^*$ and $\xi=id$.

The paper I am going through is The KPP equation as a scaling limit of locally interacting Brownian particles, https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.01031v2.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Reading your first sentence in isolation: what stops us to throw away $P$ and replace it with any other $P^*$ on $\Omega$ we want? Such other measures exist regardless what $X$ or with $(M,{\cal B})$ is.

Comment: We can choose $P$ to be whatever we want, but the $P^*$, according to which we want our new random variable to be distributed, depends on $P$. So we can't just choose $P=P^*$. This is also described after the main paragraph above. However, if we can somehow choose the random variable in that manner, that would be great.

Comment: You want $X$ to be distributed according to some probability measure $P^*$ on $\Omega\,.$ Why does anything here depend on $P$?

Comment: The sequence $P_n$ and therefore its limit $P^*$ depends on $P$.

Comment: Why we need such a sequence? You give me $X$ and $(\Omega,{\cal F})$ and I give you any $P^*$ you want.

Comment: Because that's how $P^*$ is constructed, according to which we want our random variable to be distributed. We can't just choose $P^*$ freely.

Comment: Nowhere in this paper I see $P^*$. "Then the paper goes on to say..." ***Where***?

Comment: It is on page 21, immediately after the proof of Lemma 13.